# Google Cloud: how to add role for service user to an individual bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I created a service user:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create test01 --display-name "test01"
```

And I gave him full access to Cloud Storage:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-name \
--member serviceAccount:test01@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/storage.admin
```

This code works:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()

buckets = list(client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)

bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
print list(bucket.list_blobs())
```

But my project has multiple buckets for different environments, and for security reasons I want to add access for **only one** bucket per user.

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) I found this text:

> When applied to an individual bucket, control applies only to the specified bucket and objects within the bucket.

How to apply `roles/storage.admin` to an individual bucket?

**Update:**
I tried ACL, and there is a problem: I add access to user:

```
gsutil iam ch \
  serviceAccount:test01@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com:legacyBucketOwner \
  gs://bucket-name
```

User can list all files, add files, create files, view his own files.
But user **can't view** files of other users.

**Update 2:**
I updated default ACL:

```
gsutil defacl ch -u \
  test01@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com:OWNER gs://bucket-name
```

I waited a lot of time, created another file by another user, and it's still inaccessible by `test01`.

**Solution:**
I made it from scratch, and it works:

```
gsutil mb -p example-logs -c regional -l EUROPE-WEST2 gs://example-dev
gcloud iam service-accounts create test-dev --display-name "test-dev"
gcloud iam service-accounts create test-second --display-name "test-second"
# download 2 json keys from https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:test-dev@example-logs.iam.gserviceaccount.com:legacyBucketOwner gs://example-dev
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:test-second@example-logs.iam.gserviceaccount.com:legacyBucketOwner gs://example-dev
gsutil defacl ch -u test-dev@example-logs.iam.gserviceaccount.com:OWNER gs://example-dev
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a user to work with a bucket, that user must be granted authority to work with that bucket.  This is achieved with permissions.  Permissions can be bundled into roles and we can give a user a role which means that the user will have that role.

For example, a user can be given the role "Storage Admin" and will then be able to perform work against all buckets in your project.

If that is too much, then you can choose NOT to give the user "Storage Admin" and then it will not be allowed to access any bucket.  Obviously that is too restrictive.  What you can then do is pick the individual buckets that you wish the user to access and, for each of those buckets, change the permissions of THOSE buckets.  Within the permissions of a bucket you can name users and roles.  For just THAT bucket, the named user will have the named role.

For more details see [Creating and Managing Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists).

Comment: Maybe think about a bucket like a Linux file system.  In that model, a bucket is like a directory and now you have added permissions for the user to work with new files in the directory but, just like Linux, objects in a bucket can have their own permissions.  Could it be that the objects that you place in that directory don't have permissions for your desired user to be able to read them?

Maybe try:

`gsutil ls -L gs://BUCKET/OBJECT`

Comment: I understood, but how can I make full access to bucket for one main user? If another user (e.g. gsutil in console) makes a file, in's inaccessible by main user.  In linux I can use `setfacl` to make new files accessible. But I don't know how to do it with bucket.

Comment: Let me see if I understand.   I think you want to create a bucket (XYZ) and you want that bucket to be fully accessible by user ABC.  User ABC can create, delete, read objects in the bucket.  However, if another user DEF creates an object, you are finding that ABC can't access it?  Is that the story?

Comment: It looks like we can specify default acls for newly created objects created within the bucket.  See [Creating and Managing Access Control Lists (ACLs) - Setting default object ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#defaultobjects).  Notice also the important notice that it may take 30 seconds for the change to become effective.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. I've updated my post.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't recreate the issue.  However I'm keen to assist if I can.  Ive created a chat room here where we can chat in more detail and get to a screen share if desired .... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181780/kolban

Comment: Thanks, I will create a reproducible scenario for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply storageAdmin to individual bucket like below:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:service_account_email:admin gs://bucket_name
```